# Bundle ID doesn't match any App ID

Tags: objective-c, xcode6.1

I have updated one of my iPhone apps (using the same App ID) by rewriting it from scratch to add support for new devices and add *iAd*. Somehow the App ID now has dashes where spaces used to be.  I have looked at the Provisioning Profile and there are no spaces in the app name; I have looked at the App ID and there are no spaces.  When I go to validate the app, it fails because:

> No software with CFBundleIdentifier of 'com.pragerphoneapps.Program-Name' exists.  Verify your bundle identifier is correct.  If it is, you may need to log into iTunes Connect to create the application.

So, since the bundle identifier wasn't correct I went back to iTunes Connect and attempted to re-created the application.  However, the current application has NO dashes in the name (ie. 'ProgramName'), so I didn't recreate the application for fear this update would not be treated as an update.
How can I change the App Name part of the Bundle ID to remove the dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit it from .plist file.

As you can see from the screenshot below.

[image]

By default, the app name(bundle name) is set to project name.